# Creating mousedown event with global scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, mousedown, onmousedown

I am hacking on something to fix another problem that is a constraint of the system.  Not ideal, but..

Anyway, I need to generate a click/touch then find out the topmost element under the poing `(300, 300)`.  I am using:

```
event = $.Event( "mousedown", { pageX:300, pageY:300 } );
$("window").trigger( event );
```

Then I am listening for:

```
$(window).bind 'mousedown', (jQueryEvent)->
    console.log jQueryEvent.target
```

However, `event.target` is always returning window.  This makes sense.  However, what I am trying to do is generate a mousedown event on the whole page, then use `event.target` to find out which element is under the `(pageX, pageY)`.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at http://www.zehnet.de/2010/11/19/document-elementfrompoint-a-jquery-solution/ which is a full implementation.

Comment: thanks.  Ideally I would like to figure out why this is not working becuase I want to create a range of events

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at document.elementFromPoint? This might be a clean approach to find your element at a particular position.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.elementFromPoint

Answer (score 0):

pageX and pageY are on the event variable itself, not on the target. But they get overwritten by the mousedown event. You dont need to create an event for this, closure will work just fine:

```
function hotspot (a, b) {
    var x = a[0] || 0;
    var y = a[1] || 0;
    var w = b[0] || 0;
    var h = b[1] || 0;
    function between (x2, y2) {
        return x2 >= x &&
            y2 >= y &&
            x2 <= (x + w) &&
            y2 <= (y + h);
    }
    return function (e) {
        console.log("mouse x y:", e.pageX, e.pageY);
        console.log("target x y w h:", x, y, w, h);
        console.log(between(e.pageX, e.pageY));
    }
}
$(document).on('mousedown', hotspot([0,0], [300,300]));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gpaMz/1/

Edit: re-reading your question, I just don't know what you are trying to achieve.